# mba 2012 protect data against theft

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, data

I'm looking for a way to protect my data files on my macbook air 2012

I'm a sales rep with sensitive client data. Always moving with my laptop in sleep mode.

So far I have my password set up, firewall enabled with all incoming connections blocked.

What else can I do to ensure data safety if someone gets an access to my mba SSD?

FileVault 2 is not secure (cracked in 40 minutes by security professions)
TrueCrypt looks promising but I'm concerned about battery life.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article at [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/02/03/apple-filevault-2-encryption-cracked-but-dont-panic/) which talks about the Passware Kit Forensic 11.4 software designed to 'crack' Filevault 2. However, this software can be foiled by two simple configuration points: 1/ turn off automatic login & 2/ shutdown the Mac instead of sleeping when you travel. In addition, the software requires physical access through a firewire or thunderbolt port so your computer cannot be touched through remote access.

The Privacycast site has this [detailed article](http://privacycast.com/filevault-vulnerability-how-to-protect-yourself-whole-disk-encryption-macos-lion/) for your edification.

---

Seeing that you have a MacBook Air, with its astoundingly brief startup time, I'm not sure why you keep it in sleep mode whilst traveling. I never put my MBA to sleep unless I'm at home. If somebody steals my MBA while I'm home, I have a substantially larger problem on my hands.

Comment: Sleep is overrated, lol. I think I will follow your advice on shutdown instead of sleep